# How to random mathematical operations

Tags: python

So I am creating a game where basically it asks people a few questions about what type of questions they want to answer and how many they want to answer and what not.  I am having a problem figuring out how to random mathematical operations such as addition, multiplication, and subtraction in particular.  Here is my whole code but the only part I am looking for help on is where it says "mixed" because I need to figure out how to mix the three operations.

```
import random
correct = 0

while True:
    questions = int(input("Enter the amount of questions would you like to answer: "))
    difficulty = input("Enter the difficulty of questions you would like: Beginner,    Intermediate, or Advanced: ")
math = input("Would you like to do addition, subtraction, multiplication, or mixed: ")

if difficulty == "Beginner":
    for i in range(questions):
        if math == "multiplication":
            beg1 = random.randint(1, 10)
            beg2 = random.randint(1, 10)
            prod = beg1 * beg2

            begAns = input("What is " + str(beg1) + " times " + str(beg2) + "? ")

            if int(begAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod)

        elif math == "subtraction":
            beg1 = random.randint(1, 10)
            beg2 = random.randint(1, 10)
            prod = beg1 - beg2

            begAns = input("What is " + str(beg1) + " minus " + str(beg2) + "? ")

            if int(begAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod)

        elif math == "addition":
            beg1 = random.randint(1, 10)
            beg2 = random.randint(1, 10)
            prod = beg1 + beg2

            begAns = input("What is " + str(beg1) + " plus " + str(beg2) + "? ")

            if int(begAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod)

        elif math == "mixed":
            beg1 = random.randint(1, 10)
            beg2 = random.randint(1, 10)
            prod = beg1 * beg2

            begAns = input("What is " + str(beg1) + " times " + str(beg2) + "? ")

            if int(begAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod)

elif difficulty == "Intermediate":
    for i in range(questions):
        if math == "multiplication":
            intermediate1 = random.randint(1, 25)
            intermediate2 = random.randint(1, 25)
            prod = intermediate1 * intermediate2

            intAns = input("What is " + str(intermediate1) + " times " + str(intermediate2) + "? ")

            if int(intAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod)

        elif math == "subtraction":
            intermediate1 = random.randint(1, 25)
            intermediate2 = random.randint(1, 25)
            prod = intermediate1 - intermediate2

            intAns = input("What is " + str(intermediate1) + " minus " + str(intermediate2) + "? ")

            if int(intAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod)

        elif math == "addition":
            intermediate1 = random.randint(1, 25)
            intermediate2 = random.randint(1, 25)
            prod = intermediate1 + intermediate2

            intAns = input("What is " + str(intermediate1) + " plus " + str(intermediate2) + "? ")

            if int(intAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod)

        elif math == "mixed":
            intermediate1 = random.randint(1, 25)
            intermediate2 = random.randint(1, 25)
            prod = intermediate1 + intermediate2

            intAns = input("What is " + str(intermediate1) + " times " + str(intermediate2) + "? ")

            if int(intAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod) 

elif difficulty == "Advanced":
    for i in range(questions):

        if math == "multiplication":
            adv1 = random.randint(1, 100)
            adv2 = random.randint(1, 100)
            prod = adv1 * adv2

            advAns = input("What is " + str(adv1) + " times " + str(adv2) + "? ")

            if int(advAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod)

        elif math == "subtraction":
            adv1 = random.randint(1, 100)
            adv2 = random.randint(1, 100)
            prod = adv1 - adv2

            advAns = input("What is " + str(adv1) + " minus " + str(adv2) + "? ")

            if int(advAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod)

        elif math == "addition":
            adv1 = random.randint(1, 100)
            adv2 = random.randint(1, 100)
            prod = adv1 + adv2

            advAns = input("What is " + str(adv1) + " plus " + str(adv2) + "? ")

            if int(advAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod)

        elif math == "mixed":
            adv1 = random.randint(1, 100)
            adv2 = random.randint(1, 100)
            prod = adv1 + adv2

            advAns = input("What is " + str(adv1) + " times " + str(adv2) + "? ")

            if int(advAns) == prod:
                print("That's right -- well done.\n")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("No, I'm afraid the answer is ",prod)

else:
    print("Please enter Beginner, Intermediate, or Advanced.\n")


print("\nI asked you", questions, "questions. You got ", correct, " of them right.")

if correct / questions > 2/3:
    print("Well done.\n")
elif correct / questions > 1/3:
    print("You need more practice.\n")
else:
    print("Please ask your math teacher for help!\n")

restart = input("Would you like to play again? Y/N: ")
if restart == "Y":
    continue
elif restart == "N":
    break
else:
    print("Please Enter Y or N")
```

Comment: For future reference, you should try harder to pare down your code to the specific part you want help on.  I'm didn't downvote but that's probably why someone else did.

Comment: Your code could also benefit of the use of a couple of functions, you do too many thing in one place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To randomly choose one of +, -, or * and apply it to two numbers:

```
import random
from operator import add, sub, mul

ops = (add, sub, mul)
op = random.choice(ops)

beg1, beg2 = random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10)

ans = op(beg1, beg2)
```